# Craft CMS 3 admin panel returns 404 with SSL

Tags: craft3, control-panel, 404, ssl

I'm using MAMP Pro for local development and was gong to set up my site with SSL this time around. I got a self-signed cert for local dev and I can go to my development site over https:// without any trouble but when I try to go to the control panel I get  404 error. I've updated the .htaccess file as suggested on [Enforcing SSL for CP Requests](https://craftcms.com/guides/enforcing-ssl-for-cp-requests) but I still get a 404 error. All the Stack articles I could find on this issue were of no help either. Any suggestions? Something obvious that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr:** In my case, adding `AllowOverride All` back in to httpd.conf fixed the issue.

I was having the same issue on my staging server. I noticed that, in addition to `/admin` throwing a 404, all of my site's subpages were 404-ing. This cause me to try the unrouted index.php url for a subpage (`mysite.com/index.php?p=subpage`) and it worked! Note, this wasn't working for `/index.php?p=admin` because it was properly routing to `/admin/login`. Plugging in `/index.php?p=admin/login` worked.

I ran through the [Craft guide for removing index.php from urls](https://craftcms.com/guides/removing-index-php-from-urls). Everything was set up properly, but my server admin found that `AllowOverride All` had been commented out of httpd.conf during a server update and was never un-commented. Adding `AllowOverride All` back in to httpd.conf fixed the issue.