# The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Tags: craft3, php

The frontend just work fine. But when I call the backend http://localhost/craft3/web/admin/dashboard/ or http://localhost/craft3/web/admin/ I get the error
requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80.
The admin-folder doesn't exist in web-folder.
I searched here for this problem, but they had problem with frontend.

Comment: If [you configured your webserver correctly](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/installation.html#step-5-set-up-the-web-server), you shouldn't need `web` in your URL. What URL do you use for your front-end?

Answer (score 2):

This worked just fine.
https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/35846/10953

I did all steps execpt steps 3. and 4.
Thanks all!