# can't login after move site to local - empty response

Tags: craft3, login

After migrating a site to local i can't login into the backend-part `/admin/login`.

There is an error message in the browsers console log

> VM1974:1 POST http://great-site.localhost/index.php?p=admin/actions/users/login net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I debugged into the backend until the `return $this->asJson($return);` line 1671 in UserController (vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UsersController.php).
But somehow it seems to not return anything as the browser console says.

I am on Craft Version **3.3.6**

PHP Version **7.3.18**

**Questions upfront**

Could it be that i am running on http instead https now?

Could it be that i am not creating a session correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i got it.

**It was an issue with the .htaccess**

I had not a default installation .htaccess, but a special one.

What helped in my case wa putting following into the .htaccess

```
    # Remove www from URL's
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
    RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Remove trailing slashes
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But also got issues similar to this answer afterwards: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/35846/11140